# Meizu Pro5 - Can't connect to a secured internet

Tags: networking, 15.04, internet

I have a Meizu Pro5 and am unable to connect to a password secured Internet. I type in the password and nothing happens. Unsecured, I can connect just fine. Tried to connect on two different wireless connections, no go. Also Since the Upgrade to OTA-12 Deko does not work, nor does my video. Of course, since I can not connect to the Internet, I can not download any patches, if any exist.

Help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to connect as if it were a hidden network.
If it still doesn't work you might also temporarily set the developers mode ON before trying to connect.
This worked for me, but it is weird, I agree. Something to be improved indeed.

Hope it helps (if you did not already find out).

Jan

Comment: Treating the connection as a hidden network worked!  Thanks a heap. 
Now if only i can get the video and Deko Email to  work ... .